# Как вставить if в return?

Tags: python

Как вставить if в return? То есть чтобы return возвращал определенные значения в зависимости от условия if?

```
return({str(year)+':'+
        if month<10:
            month = '0'+str(month)
        else:
            month=str(month)
        +':'+
        if day < 10:
            day = '0'+str(day)
        else:
            day=str(day)
        +' '+
        if hours<10:
            hours = '0'+str(hours)
        else:
            hours = str(hours
        +':'+
        if minuteNew < 10:
            minuteNew='0'+str(minute)
        else:
            minuteNew=str(minuteNew)
        +str(second)})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь форматированием строк.

Пример:

```
year = 2021
month = 3
day = 9
hours = 15
minute = 1
res = f"{year}:{month:02d}:{day:02d} {hours:02d}:{minute:02d}"
```

результат:

```
In [21]: res
Out[21]: '2021:03:09 15:01'
```

Т.е. в вашем случае `return` будет выглядеть так:

```
return f"{year}:{month:02d}:{day:02d} {hours:02d}:{minute:02d}"
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно решение вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте тернарные операторы.

К примеру:

```
return False if True == True else True
```